# Where is the Module class located in Prestashop? (Not ModuleCore)

Tags: php, prestashop

I see that in Prestashop all Modules extend from the "Module" class but when I try to locate this class and look for it in the "classes/module/Module.php" file, I see this definition:

```
abstract class ModuleCore
```

but no trace of the actual "Module" class, as if "Module" was some alias of the "ModuleCore" class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what this is. `ModuleCore` is an alias for the Module Class, as all other classes in Prestashop.

It is used for overriding.
Default classes are called `ItemCore`.

So to override, you declare : `class Item extends ItemCore`

Comment: So if i understand you, Module "extends" ModuleCore and "SomeModule" "extends" Module? If so, where is defined that Module "extends" ModuleCore?? Thanks.

Comment: Module and ModuleCore are the same classes. Module is always the class called : if you have an override, it calls /override/classes/module/Module.php, else, ModuleCore is called. You can see the autoload file for more info (/cache/class_index.php).

Comment: autoload.php file was so clarifying! (classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php in PS 1.6). Thank you!